# httpd Server not started: (13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:88

Tags: apache, centos

I am trying to start httpd server on centos 6. It throws following error :

```
[root@machine ~]# service httpd start
Starting httpd: (13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:88
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:88
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
                                                           [FAILED]
```

I have also checked for port 88, It is not is use.
I also checked with [semanage](http://rmohan.com/?p=1595), but it didn't help.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Adding the port to SELinux worked for me, so thanks for the link.

Comment: Edit the conf to change the port Apache uses to a number greater than 1024, like 8080  for example. I was using Ubuntu v20 in windows and editing like: sudo vi /etc/apache2/ports.conf

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Seems like you are running it not as "root". Only root can bind to this port (80). 
Check your configuration in the conf/httpd.conf file, Listen line and change the port to higher one.

Comment: you could use `sudo`

Comment: @Andrew, no I couldnt, didnt have the privileges

Comment: Thank you! In my case, I was using the `USER X` command in the Dockerfile which was the cause of the problem. Commenting it set the root as the default user again, and everything worked fine

Answer (score 135):

I happened to run into this problem because of **missing SELinux permissions**. By default, SELinux only allowed apache/httpd to bind to the following ports:

```
80, 81, 443, 488, 8008, 8009, 8443, 9000
```

So binding to my `httpd.conf`-configured `Listen 88` HTTP port and `config.d/ssl.conf`-configured `Listen 8445` TLS/SSL port would fail with that default SELinux configuration.

To fix my problem, I had to add ports 88 and 8445 to my system's SELinux configuration:

1. Install `semanage` tools: `sudo yum -y install policycoreutils-python`
2. Allow port 88 for httpd: `sudo semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 88`
3. Allow port 8445 for httpd: `sudo semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 8445`

Comment: I think that I had the same issue on Mac OS X (Darwin, Unix variant). Listening on port 88 **seemed** to restart just fine and didn't throw any errors, but I couldn't get any response back in the browser on that port. Once I changed it to 81 though it started working just fine.

Comment: use dnf install policycoreutils-python-utils on Fedora 24

Comment: see here for allow non root to bind certain ports: https://superuser.com/a/892391/216033

Comment: -m option (modify) worked for as the port i needed already defined for other selinux policy.

Comment: @Abdull, this sol is specific to the rpm based OS. what to do on debian or ubuntu

Answer (score 20):

This is an addition to the answer by Abdull somewhere in this thread:

I had to modify instead of adding a port

`semanage port -m -t http_port_t -p tcp  5000`

because I get this error on adding the port

`ValueError: Port tcp/5000 already defined`

Comment: This worked for me, although I added the SELinux policy & it was a success, still I needed to do this to make it work, ate up 30 minutes from my life :(

Answer (score 8):

At terminal run this command with root permission:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

You must be root for starting a webserver otherwise you would get similar error.

Comment: true the root user access is needed. SO Sudo service apache2 restart will also restart like you have written with sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start

Answer (score 7):

With my centos 6.7 installation, not only did I have the problem starting httpd with root but also with xauth (getting `/usr/bin/xauth: timeout in locking authority file /.Xauthority` with underlying permission denied errors)

`# setenforce 0`

Fixed both issues.

Comment: That solved my problems on a Centos 7 on a vagrant driven dev server running apache2 on another port. Keep in mind though that you are actually disabling SELinux – meaning disabling security features. On a production server better use `semanage` to add the port as @Abdull mentioned

Answer (score 6):

**Disable SELinux**

Disable SELinux temporarily

```
sudo setenforce 0
```

Restart httpd service

```
service httpd restart
```

Disable SELinux persistently (after reboot)

```
vi /etc/selinux/config
```

Add line and save

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

Comment: I recommend disabling SELinux, start the webserver and do
`grep -a AVC /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep httpd | audit2allow -a -M myhttpd`
enable your myhttpd policy with `semodule -i myhttpd.pp` and enable SELinux again.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I tried to first use port 88 instead, and even then the httpd won't start.

I used the below command, i.e. modify instead of add, as suggested by one of users, and was able to run httpd.

```
semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 88
```

Answer (score 1):

after disable SELINUX, any port is aviable.

```bash
sudo -s;  
setenforce 0;  
sed -i 's/SELINUX=enforcing/SELINUX=disabled/g' /etc/selinux/config;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Linux(Centos 6 or higher) ports from 0 to 1024 are reserved for system use.
you can force the system to bind to address any port lower than 1024 if you use root or privileged user.

I installed Apache-2.4 from source with non-root user and I solved this problem by allowing port higher than 1024(ex:8080) and modified http.conf file. chang Listen 80 to Listen 8080

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error while trying to start httpd service for openstack train installation in RHEL 7.5 too.

```
-- Unit httpd.service has begun starting up.
Jan 31 10:11:16 controller httpd[1631]: (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 10.0.0.11:5000
Jan 31 10:11:16 controller httpd[1631]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Jan 31 10:11:16 controller httpd[1631]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Jan 31 10:11:16 controller systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 31 10:11:16 controller kill[1632]: kill: cannot find process ""
Jan 31 10:11:16 controller systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 31 10:11:16 controller systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed
```

Solution: It got resolved by disabling SElinux.

Answer (score 0):

I edited `/etc/selinux/config`, set `SELINUX=disabled`, then reboot; then it worked.
Alternately, you can run `setenforce 0`; you don't need reboot, but this is once used.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add more info about this error, I had the similar error on CentOS 8.2:

`sudo journalctl -xe`

Error:
Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:8081

So, I used the commands from Abdull and Ulrich-Lorenz Schlüter as a follow:

1. Install semanage tools for CentOS 8.2: `sudo yum -y install policycoreutils-python-utils`
   (For more info: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redhat-install-semanage-selinux-command-rpm )
2. Allow port 8081 for httpd: `sudo semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 8081`

I got the following output: ValueError: Port tcp/8081 already defined

So, I ran:

`sudo semanage port -m -t http_port_t -p tcp 8081`

As Ulrich-Lorenz Schlüter mentioned.

3. Then: `sudo systemctl start httpd`

Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The actual solution here is to modify the existing port if it exists. For instance, when:

```
semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 88
```

ends up with:

```
ValueError: Port tcp/88 already defined
```

then it's very likely the port is having a different type, and to modify it, simply use:

```
semanage port -m -t http_port_t -p tcp 88
```

and then, you need to open that port via `firewall-cmd` if has been closed in your zone.

Also: *disabling SELinux is a potential security vulnerability, don't do this on production instances!*

Answer (score 0):

1. Check security state

   getenforce
2. Check firewall state

   firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-all
3. Check excution permission

   Go to httpd/bin

   #chown root:[YOUR ACCOUNT] ./httpd

   #chmod +s ./httpd

And re-running services

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If someone works with Windows and has installed Linux with WSL. For me i had this issue:

** Restarting Apache httpd web server apache2                                                                           (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.*

And to fix it i opend a powershell as administrator and taped this:

> net stop http

tap Y and try again the command to start apache.

Answer (score -1):

Start with root user or with sudo, it works fine, here is sample output:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-12-164 ~]$ service httpd start
Starting httpd: (13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
                                                           **[FAILED]**
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-12-164 ~]$ sudo service httpd start
Starting httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-12-164 ~]$ sudo service httpd status
httpd (pid  3077) is running...
```

Answer (score -5):

First kill all the hanged instances of httpd, and then try restarting Apache:

```
service httpd restart
```